# Pixel coordinates for WebGL canvas context different than 2d context canvas

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, webgl

I have two canvases. One is 2d and the other is webgl. However giving them the same positioning coordinates their contents lie on different places. Even though the contents of one canvas should be on top of the other.

If I do this: `gl.scissor(150, 500, 100, 90);` then they come on top of each other but how can I make it so when I give them the same coordinates they lie on same positions.

Here's the fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/1L6qdhta/

And here's the code:

```
#canvas1,
#canvas2 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#canvas-wrapper {
  Width: 100%;
  Height: 80vh;
}
```

```
<div id="canvas-wrapper">
  <canvas id="canvas1" height="720" width="1280"></canvas>
  <canvas id="canvas2" height="720" width="1280"></canvas>
</div>
```

```
const canvas1 = document.querySelector("#canvas1");
const gl = canvas1.getContext("webgl");

gl.enable(gl.SCISSOR_TEST);
gl.scissor(150, 150, 100, 90);
gl.clearColor(0, 0.25, 0, 0.25);
gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

const canvas2 = document.querySelector("#canvas2");
const ctx = canvas2.getContext("2d");
ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(255,0,255,0.25)";
ctx.font = "55px san-serif";
ctx.textAlign = "center";
ctx.fillText("layer 3", 150, 150);
```

Comment: How are you expecting them to be on top of each other? Do you want the background from webgl and the text from ctx?

Comment: Both canvases have clear background. I just want the layer3 on top of the webgl square given same pixel coordinates.